# vertically aligning an image with text, including ie

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

What's the best way to do this?

Here is my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b8xFk.jpg" /> <span id="text">Twitter</span>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#wrapper{
  background-color:orange;
  height:60px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#wrapper #text{
  line-height:60px; 
}
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSQmg/)

As you can see, the image is lower than the text (at least in Firefox 16). In ie things get even more wonky. What are the best practices for vertically aligning an image with text for cross-browser compatibility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. This is the way I am trying to do it. Not sure if there is a cleaner way. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
<a href="#">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b8xFk.jpg" />
    <span class="bar">&nbsp;Facebook </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color:orange;
}

.bar{
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 26px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.foo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.foo a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Finally, here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Md3uE/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#wrapper img{
  vertical-align:middle;
  /*New:*/
  padding-bottom:4px;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ZSQmg/2/)**

Comment: Thanks karacas, this works for this specific problem, but is there a universal way to handle this in all situations? I've been using the solution below, which takes more time, but seems to work. Not sure if one is better or not :)